# Barrel/"Paris" hinge pivot orientation

Tags: doors, hinges

I've seen some doors in Europe with mixed barrel hinge (Fr. "paumelle de Paris") orientation. Unusually these have the pivot pointing up, but occasionally I've seen a door with one of hinges mounted the other way around, i.e. with the pivot pointing down. Is there a reason for this?

[image]

For outdoor use I understand this is a bad idea because a barrel hinge will gather water when mounted upside down. The ones I saw upside down were all inside doors. Also, it wasn't done because of the lack of proper parts (left vs right hinge). They simply rotated the hinge completely with the pivot installed on the door rather than the jamb. I don't get it why anyone would do this.

[image]

Comment: I know these as "flag hinges". [REF 1](https://www.dndhardware.com/What-Is-a-Flag-Hinge-id582380.html) and [REF 2](https://monroeengineering.com/flag-hinges.php).

Comment: This is just a guess, therefore not posting as an answer, but my first thought would be that the installer simply did not consider the orientation while installing, or did not care.

Answer (score 0):

These hinges, when both are mounted with the pin facing up with pin side mounted to the door jamb OR when both are mounted with the pin facing down with the pin side secured to the door - it allows the door to be easily removed.

When one hinge is flipped the opposite direction with one pin pointing up and the other one pointing down it prevents the removal of the door. Pretty simple actually.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. You can still lift the door even with a mixture of pin/pivot orientations.

Comment: And if the hinge is installed incorrectly it falls apart.

Comment: @Fizz it locks door to hinges and door can only be removed by removing one hinge.  Farm gates use same idea, easy to remove both pins up, hard to remove bottom pin up, top pin down.  Barrel/pin holes welded to gate.

Comment: @crip659, that would require one left-hand and one right-hand hinge. Two of the same (as they're usually sold) mounted in opposing directions doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the use case. Do you want the pointy hinge leaf on the door opening or on the door when it's apart, say for storage? Is water collection a concern? There's no right or wrong.